# How to check UFS filesystem on SPARC with Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris, ufs

I've got this really old Solaris SPARC machine. It doesn't boot any longer for some as yet unknown reason (seems like the disk may be corrupted). I'd like to check the partitions. The only thing I could think of was to boot it with a systemrescue cd (Linux on SPARC).

But fsck doesn't seem to support UFS, and there's no testdisk available, at least on this version of systemrescue.

Any ideas on how I could possibly go about checking (and possibly subsequently recovering and mounting) the filesystems on the several partitions that are physically connected?

Comment: Use Solaris installation media to boot, either to entirely in memory or using only the swap partition. The Solaris `fsck` will support the filesystem(s) in use. In general, Linux filesystems are not Solaris filesystems.

Comment: If fsck show you weird information or fails, it probably means that your fs indexes are corrupted

Comment: UFS is also endian-dependent, so you won't be able to remove the drive and check a SPARC UFS file system from a Linux x86 host.  From the old OpenSolaris forums:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.solaris.opensolaris.general/2618

Answer (score 2):

Use Solaris installation media to boot, either to entirely in memory or using only the swap partition. The Solaris `fsck` will support the filesystem(s) in use. In general, Linux filesystems are not Solaris filesystems.

You can get Solaris 11 boot media [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/install-2245079.html). Try the ''live media'' entry for x86 hosts.